# Erro na migração de aplicação, incompatibilidade ANTLR e Wildfly 8

Tags: java, glassfish, wildfly

Tenho uma aplicação legada desenvolvida em Java web, e gostaria de colocar ela em um novo ambiente de produção. Neste ambiente está instalado o Java 8 e a última versão do Wildfly. Hoje essa aplicação roda em um servidor Java 7 no Glassfish (não me lembro da versão, mas não é tão desatualizada) sem problemas.

O problema que está ocorrendo é seguinte, quando eu tento fazer o deploy da aplicação no Wildfly ele dá o seguinte erro:

```
"{\"JBAS014671: Failed services\" => {
\"jboss.persistenceunit.\\\"Projeto.war#ProjetoBasePU\\\"\" => \"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\\\"Projeto.war#ProjetoBasePU\\\": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: ProjetoBasePU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: ProjetoBasePU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to parse order-by fragment
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: antlr.CommonToken cannot be cast to antlr.Token\",
\"jboss.persistenceunit.\\\"Projeto.war#ProjetoBaseTestPU\\\"\" => \"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\\\"Projeto.war#ProjetoBaseTestPU\\\": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: ProjetoBaseTestPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: ProjetoBaseTestPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to parse order-by fragment
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: antlr.CommonToken cannot be cast to antlr.Token\"
```

Realizando alguns testes, eu removi das bibliotecas do projeto o `jar` da ANTLR, isso fez com que esse erro desaparecesse, a aplicação faz o deploy normalmente, mas ai acontece o seguinte erro quando tento acessar a primeira tela do sistema:

```
14:11:41,484 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6) javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;

14:11:41,484 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:848)

14:11:41,484 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:777)

14:11:41,485 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:193)

14:11:41,485 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69)

14:11:41,485 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)

14:11:41,485 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:366)

14:11:41,485 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)

14:11:41,485 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)

14:11:41,485 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)

14:11:41,486 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)

14:11:41,486 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)

14:11:41,486 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at br.edu.unifeob.sguprofessor.filtros.FiltroHibernate.doFilter(FiltroHibernate.java:51)

14:11:41,486 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)

14:11:41,486 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)

14:11:41,486 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)

14:11:41,486 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)

14:11:41,486 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)

14:11:41,487 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)

14:11:41,487 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)

14:11:41,487 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113)

14:11:41,487 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)

14:11:41,487 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)

14:11:41,487 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)

14:11:41,488 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61)

14:11:41,488 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)

14:11:41,488 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)

14:11:41,488 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)

14:11:41,488 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)

14:11:41,524 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

14:11:41,524 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)

14:11:41,524 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)

14:11:41,524 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240)

14:11:41,524 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)

14:11:41,525 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73)

14:11:41,525 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146)

14:11:41,525 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177)

14:11:41,525 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727)

14:11:41,525 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

14:11:41,525 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

14:11:41,525 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

14:11:41,526 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;

14:11:41,526 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at br.edu.unifeob.sgu.uteis.HibernateConnection.getSession(HibernateConnection.java:56)

14:11:41,526 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at br.edu.unifeob.sgu.uteis.HibernateConnection.beginTransaction(HibernateConnection.java:107)

14:11:41,526 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at br.edu.unifeob.sguprofessor.taglibs.hibernatetag.HibernateQuery.doEndTag(HibernateQuery.java:65)

14:11:41,526 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspx_meth_hibernate_005fquery_005f0(login_jsp.java:326)

14:11:41,526 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:141)

14:11:41,527 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)    ... 37 more
```

Alguém já passou por isso?

Comment: Antes de fazer o deploy você deve migrar toda a infra da sua aplicação para o wildfly. Aparentemente você não fez isso com o Hibernate.

Comment: Como assim? O que quis dizer com isso?

Comment: Cara, não é só pegar o ear, dar deploy e pronto. Quem dera se fosse assim. O Jboss, assim como o glassfish, é um container e vai fornecer uma infraestrutura básica para sua aplicação. Você tem uma série de bibliotecas e jar's que vão rodar no seu jboss, isso é que eu chamo de infraestrutura. Você deve se certificar que o seu jboss tenha tudo isso funcionando antes de fazer o deploy.

Comment: Já tenho duas aplicações rodando lá sem problema nenhum, o problema é com está da duvida.

Comment: Sua implementação usa JPA puro ? ou tem features específicas do Hibernate ? Oque o @EdgarMunizBerlinck faz todo sentido, não é só ir mudando assim de ambiente, outro detalhe é referente ao Java 8, Wildfly só tem suporte para Java 7, nunca tentei rodar nesse ambiente, mas te aconselho a migrar com cuidado e de preferencia em cima do jdk 1.7 mesmo.

Comment: Tem algumas coisas de hibernate pelo meio também, e sobre o suporte ao Java 8, no release final do Wildfly 8 segundo o próprio site deles ele já tinha uma certa compatibilidade com o Java 8, que estava sendo melhorada, e já estamos no Wildfly 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Eu queria colocar como comentário mas não estou conseguindo.

14:11:41,484 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6) javax.servlet.ServletException: **[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html)**: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;

Provavelmente está tendo uma incompatibilidade de versões neste meio tempo. Isso ocorre normalmente quando você compila em uma versão e o ambiente de execução está em outra.

Ex: Compilou local como Hiberante 3 e no seu JBoss tem Hibernate 4, e o método openSession() não está disponível no objeto SessionFactory do Hibernate 4.

**[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html)**:

> Thrown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class (either static or instance), and that class no longer has a definition of that method.
>   **Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.**

### Sugestão adicional

Dentro do JBoss já se encontra disponível uma versão de Hibernate 4, certifique-se de remover da sua aplicação qualquer outra versão de Hibernate.